# How to enable a custom resolution with nvidia & xorg

Tags: linux, xorg, nvidia, edid

Does anyone know the proper settings to use when wanting to enable a resolution not exposed by `EDID` in a `DVI` display? I've extensively searched for the right `xorg.conf` settings but it seems the driver ignores any custom display `modeset` as invalid even when bypassing `EDID` checks.

I know for a fact that the resolution I'm trying to achieve, while not in the display's `EDID`, is supported by the display (used in Windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

Get your monitor's `EDID` and save it to a file.  You can do that from Linux, with [read-edid](http://polypux.org/projects/read-edid/).

Then go to Windows and get the parameters for the working mode.  I no longer remember the details (I had to do this only once, and it was a few years ago), but there are Windows utilities for that, and they're pretty easy to find.

Then edit the `EDID` file to include the new mode.  I think I wrote a Perl script at the time, but you might be able to find other (Windows) utilities to do that for you.

If you end up having to do the plumbing yourself, the format is described at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data), and there are a few posts here that might help you, such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97023/117516), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114359/117516), and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109693/117516).  In particular there's an [edid-generator](https://github.com/akatrevorjay/edid-generator) program that looks like an useful start.

Beware that the order of entries in the `EDID` file is important.  If I recall correctly you want your preferred mode first.

When you have the cooked `EDID` file copy it to Linux, and point `xorg` to it.  Back when I did that I had to add an option like this to the `Device` section in my `xorg.conf`:

```
Option    "CustomEDID"    "DFP-1:/etc/X11/EDID.bin"
```

These days `Xorg` ignores `xorg.conf`, so you'll have to hunt around to re-enable it.  The `CustomEDID` is documented in nVidia driver's docs; you'll need to adjust that too, to fit your particular setup.